# ¿Cómo puedo usar clearinterval dentro de una función con un label?

Tags: javascript, algoritmos

**Buenas, quiero resolver este algoritmo:**

El caballo de Mac es más oscuro que el de Smith, pero más rápido y más viejo que el de Jack, que es aún más lento que el de Willy, que es más jóven que el de Mac, que es más viejo que el de Smith, que es más claro que el de Willy, aunque el de Jack es más lento y más oscuro que el de Smith. ¿Cuál es el más viejo, cuál el más lento y cuál el más claro?

Traté con el siguiente código pero no me funciona:

```
function calc_property(t, l, e){
            this.mac = {t: t, l: l, e: e};
            this.smith = {t: t, l: l, e: e};
            this.jack = {t: t, l: l, e: e};
            this.willy = {t: t, l: l, e: e};
        }
        calc_property.prototype.getInfo = function(){
            let mac = this.mac;
            let smith = this.smith;
            let jack = this.jack;
            let willy = this.willy;
            intervalo: setInterval(function(){
                mac = {t: Math.ceil(Math.random(mac.t) * 2), l: Math.ceil(Math.random(mac.l) * 2), e: Math.ceil(Math.random(mac.e) * 2)};
                smith = {t: Math.ceil(Math.random(smith.t) * 2), l: Math.ceil(Math.random(smith.l) * 2), e: Math.ceil(Math.random(smith.e) * 2)};
                jack = {t: Math.ceil(Math.random(jack.t) * 2), l: Math.ceil(Math.random(jack.l) * 2), e: Math.ceil(Math.random(jack.e) * 2)};
                willy = {t: Math.ceil(Math.random(willy.t) * 2), l: Math.ceil(Math.random(willy.l) * 2), e: Math.ceil(Math.random(willy.e) * 2)};
                if(mac.t > smith.t && 
                mac.l > jack.l && 
                mac.e > jack.e &&
                willy.l > jack.l &&
                mac.e > willy.e &&
                mac.e > smith.e &&
                willy.t > smith.t &&
                smith.l > jack.e &&
                jack.t > smith.t){
                    clearInterval(this);
                    console.log("Caballo de Mac: ", mac);
                    console.log("Caballo de Smith: ", smith);
                    console.log("Caballo de Jack: ", jack);
                    console.log("Caballo de Willy: ", willy);
                }
            }, 1, mac, smith, jack, willy)
        }
        let propiedades = new calc_property(5, 10, 15);
        propiedades.getInfo();
```

Quiero hacerlo sin clases, ya que quiero aprender los fundamentos de los prototipos primero antes de irme con las clases.

**Me pregunto:** ¿Cómo puedo hacer que un intervalo se limpie si está adentro de un label (intervalo:), ya traté poniendo el mismo nombre del label adentro de la función (donde dice "this"), pero no me funciona?

Gracias y bendiciones.

Comment: Un prototipo no tiene mucha ciencia detras pues enrealidad en `javascript` los prototipos son simplemente una forma de extender la funcionalidad e información de todas las instancias de una clase o un objeto **NO** primitivo, o de por si creo que incluso puedes reformular la clase en si o sobreescribirla haciendo unos pequeños hacks, pero realmente no hay mucho mas que aprender de los prototipos, solo son usados en su mayor parte para esto.

Comment: Porque tienes `invervalo: setInterval...`?, en esa parte tienes un error, haz revisado como se declara un `Objeto`?, el problema es que tu `tag` no hace parte de un objeto, practicamente te estas inventando una nueva sintaxis que no reconoce `JS`.

Comment: Continuando con lo dicho por @Riven, en lugar de propiedad, usa una variable: `let intervalo = setInterval(function(){ ...` y dentro de la función puedes cancelar con `clearInterval(intervalo);`. Por otra parte, estuve probando y puede tomar mucho tiempo llegar a una solución, tal vez debas ampliar los resultados generados por `Math.random()`

Comment: Hola @Triby, lo puce como una variable y no funciona.
Supongo que tendre que tratar con clases, solamente quería hacerlo así para practicar y aprender.